# how to replace text using variable in PHP?

Tags: php, string, erase

im doing to using STOP WORD for erase some conjuntion words : like this, the, in .

im still using read string then replace from file then erase those conjuntion words and here is the code

```
$fh = fopen("search/E_a_02.txt", "r");

$file = file_get_contents("search/E_a_02.txt");
$stop="BI";
echo str_replace($stop, "", $file);
```

i want that variable $stop is like array , that include stop words, then erase the sentence from the file, what should i do?

pleaseee help.

thank you master :)

Comment: Removing an array of words wont be a problem, you can give an array to `str_replace` and it will replace all those, but it gets trick when you say remove the whole sentence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$stop = array("this","the","in");
echo str_replace($stop, "", $file);
```

It should replace all occurrence of $stop in $file

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$fh = fopen("search/E_a_02.txt", "r");

$file = file_get_contents("search/E_a_02.txt");

$stop=array("BI","BE");

echo str_replace($stop, "", $file);
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: remember they said remove the whole sentence?